# How do I copy a mesh onto another mesh using the surface normal?

Tags: modeling, mesh, normals

I would like to copy one mesh onto another's surface using the surface normal. I would like to specify a vertex group for this.

I tried to use particle/hair for this but could not get exactly one copy per vertex.

I tried keeping the object origin at (0,0,0) but editing the vertices so that the copied object is oriented along the y axis and then making it a child of the surface object and turned on vertex instancing. I can't specify the vertex group nor change the instances to new meshes so that I can delete the ones that are outside the vertex group.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe look into using a ShrinkWrap modifier.

Comment: about the particle solution: you just need to know how many vertices you have on your surface (select all in Edit mode and check the status bar), then use this number as Emission > Number?

Comment: I had used random order on particles and changing this, along with your suggestion, moonboots, works. It is inelegant (since it ignores the vertex group), but not that much work. This is one of those occasional things that are easier done in C4D, Houdini, or Modo.